# Object function Date() { [native code] } has no method 'compareTo' when use Date.js in Chrome

Tags: javascript, datejs

I have these two date time variables in javascript:

```
first_date = Date.parse('05/21/2012 0:00:00 ');
second_date = Date.today();
```

If I'm using ( http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#compareTo )

```
return first_date.compareTo(second_date)
```

then exception occurs:

`Object function Date() { [native code] } has no method 'compareTo'` in Google Chrome.

I'm using latest version of Date.js from http://www.datejs.com/

How to solve this issue ?

I will mention that other functions (add(-5).days(), today(), etc.) works fine.

PS: I took a look here ( http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?id=129 ) but no workaround.

Comment: `first_date` isn't a Date, it's a string, so that would explain why it doesn't have a `compareTo` method. You mention Chrome several times - does that imply your code does work in other browsers, or that you haven't tested in other browsers? The latest version of date.js that I downloaded didn't seem to define a `compare` method, just `compareTo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`first_date` and `second_date` are strings according to your code and `Date.compare` does not even exist unless you are using the [svn-trunk version](http://datejs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build/date-en-US.js).

datejs defines `Date.prototype.compareTo` so you can only use `date_obj_a.compareTo(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
first_date = Date.parse('05/21/2012 0:00:00 ');
second_date = Date.today();

console.log(first_date.compareTo(second_date)); // just working fine
```

Comment: I have error `Object function Date() { [native code] } has no method 'compare'` ...

Comment: Why not just remove the `toString` in the second line instead of converting date->string->date?

Comment: I modified the variables but same error. The Chrome doesn't see `compare` or `compareTo` function !!!

Comment: @MichaelSwan - The latest date.js file doesn't define `compare` (regardless of what the documentation says).

Comment: Yes, I understood, but I removed compare and I used compareTo

Comment: @MichaelSwan yup, you should use `compareTo()`